# How to center plots in layout plot Julia?

Tags: plot, layout, julia

I have the following reproducible odd layout plot:

```
using Plots
plot(rand(100, 5), layout = 5)
```

Output:

[image]

As you can see plot number 4 and 5 are not centered, but the are left aligned. I would like these to be more centered without changing their height and width so they stay the same as other plots. So I was wondering if anyone knows how to center these plots in a `layout` plot in `Julia`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE: As requested, the layout has to keep all the plots of same size:

```
p1 = plot(rand(10));
p2 = plot(rand(10));
p3 = plot(rand(10));
p4 = plot(rand(10));
p5 = plot(rand(10));

pb1 = plot(legend=false,grid=false,foreground_color_subplot=:white);
pb2 = plot(legend=false,grid=false,foreground_color_subplot=:white);

l = @layout [grid(1,3); grid(1,4, widths=[1/6,1/3,1/3,1/6])]

plot(p1,p2,p3,pb1,p4,p5,pb2; layout = l)
```

Giving:
[image: Updated image]

Try:

```
julia> l = @layout [grid(1,3); grid(1,2)]
2×1 Matrix{Any}:
 Plots.GridLayout(1, 3)
 Plots.GridLayout(1, 2)

julia> plot(rand(10,5); layout = l)
```

[image: Layout image]

Mostly self explanatory, but there is also more material on layouts at:
https://docs.juliaplots.org/latest/layouts/

Comment: Hi @Dan Getz, thank you for your answer! I really like your solution, but I would like to have the plots 4 and 5 to have the same width as plot 1,2 and 3. Now the width is higher. Do you understand what I mean?

Comment: Fixed the code a bit. I think the widths are not exactly the same yet, but this can be changed in the `widths` layout parameter and can be accurately calculated by considering margins, axes and the like.

Comment: If-I-recall-correctly Makie.jl has nice provisions for such layouts.